# Design for search by date or year

Tags: gui-design, search

I need to enable user to filter displayed data by date ( 11.2.2015 ) or by year.

My current design is illustrated below:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frLcoh.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

When user checks radio button I enable corresponding date picker and perform filtering.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments I think those two approaches would be good:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk0rtY.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

About the by year / by date select (radio) I can't think of one being better in every sense (e.g: a dropdown with year/date is more clean but less explicit, all-in-all controls would minize the amount of text/controls but their far for being common, etc)

---

btw, I was preparing an answer to your yesterday's related question before it was deleted, here my mockup

[image]

Comment: *btw, I was preparing an answer to your yesterday's related question before it was deleted* Sorry for that, it was closed and I got an advice to rephrase it. I decided to delete it and narrow it down to the problem with date. I have upvoted your answer. I will wait a little before officially accept. Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: This is one of the "one fits all" solutions that I can think, but I could think of other approaches having more information: 1) This is the date of what event?(e.g. a purchase) 2) Is there one type of search that will be quite more frequent? 3) are the dates usually recent or they could be usually for example from 1998? 4) what kind of users will use it?

Comment: *1) This is the date of what event?* date ( or year ) of signing the contract; *2) Is there one type of search that will be quite more frequent?* I assume it would be easier to filter by year first, and then narrow down by date; *3) are the dates usually recent or they could be usually for example from 1998?* I think they can be from 1998 as well; *4) what kind of users will use it?* "regular" computer user, someone who uses computer for work/Internet browsing/Youtube/Facebook etc...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff I've done a further research and taking in account your last comment I've edited the answer which I think it's quite "cleaner" and according to your case than the OP one.

Comment: I will go with the second option from your edited mockup... Too bad nothing simpler could have been suggested. Thank you for your help. Officially accepted. As for your answer to my deleted question: I am preparing new question, so if you are interested I can leave you a comment here once I post it...

Comment: Date is not a simple control because there are many ways in which it could be enter and selected, also there are a lot possible formats, so yes it's difficult to get a really satisfactory unless it's a very specific case. Ok, comment if you want and I'll try to help.